# How to route users to different backend Hostnames via products in Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

i am having Set of API's having same backend Host for production and acceptance.

```
https://api.azurewebsites.net/vendor, 
https://api.azurewebsites.net/session, 
https://api.azurewebsites.net/api

https://api.acc.azurewebsites.net/vendor, 
https://api.acc.azurewebsites.net/session, 
https://api.acc.azurewebsites.net/api,
```

So, i want to create 2 products xyz-production & xyz-acceptance and route clients to respective ENV backend Host.

I tried to achieve same with "set-backend-service" policy. `<set-backend-service base-url="https://<Host Name>/<Path>" />` But this policy allowed to change only **serviceURL**.

But my requirement is to change only Hostname. Could you please suggest, how to achieve it?

Comment: set-backend-service still the solution, just set the base URL and it should automatically append the operation URL

Comment: @MohamadHaidar yes, If I use base URL, Operation URL will automatically append. 

But this way, I can only route one API for product. For my scenario, I like to route set of API's acceptance host which having different Base URL's.

Comment: So why not using the policy at the product level? Just go to the product and assign the policy there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for this question is below. By using "context.Api.Path" variable we can append API's base path dynamically with any Host you want.

```
<set-backend-service base-url="@("https://api.acc.azurewebsites.net" + context.Api.Path)" />
```